# Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 0.)

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am getting this error during debugging the build.

unable to read property list from file:

/Users/..TestApp/FastApp/ios/FastApp/Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 0.)

Answer (score 16):

You can navigate in the Terminal to the file and execute `plutil ./Info.plist` which should show you where the issue is. Then fix in a text editor

Comment: In my case It sows the status OK for the info.plist but still having error. Is there any other solution?