# Unable to read property list from file even though Info.plist is OK

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

I was using the Swift Package Manager to install Firebase to my Xcode project as I was trying to avoid that hassle with CocoaPods. Strangely, my entire Xcode project is no longer building. I removed the Firebase dependency from my project but I kept receiving error after error. Eventually I got stuck on the following:

> error: unable to read property list from file: /Users/*USER*/Desktop/Developer/*APPNAME*/*APPNAME*: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 2.) (in target '*APPNAME*' from project '*APPNAME*')

I have the Target Membership checkbox unchecked for `Info.plist`. I tried the basic troubleshooting steps:

1. Deleting derived data
2. Cleaning the build folder
3. Closing and reopening Xcode
4. Restarting my computer

None of these steps made any changes (I didn't really expect them to, but they were worth the try). My property list file had no changes made to it except adding additional application fonts and changing the view controller status bar color to light content. The file path is correct and nothing seems unusual about the file. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918946/info-plist-the-operation-couldn-t-be-completed-xcbutil-propertylistconversion) answer from Stack Overflow to run a terminal command `plutil ./Info.plist` on my `Info.plist` file but the terminal read back `./Info.plist: OK`.

I don't understand what could be causing this issue. I am not sure if it is related to Swift Package Manager, but this was something that occurred after installing the Firebase iOS SDK.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be an issue that occurred in the Build Settings. I fixed this by going to Project File > Build Settings > Packaging > Info.plist File and press delete on your keyboard (or select your files route folder).