# error (Xcode): unable to read property list from file:

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, plist

Error (Xcode): unable to read property list from file:
ios/Runner
/Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed.
(XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 2.)

help me someone?

Comment: Can you post your info.plist here?

Comment: Maybe you change the directory of info.plist. and I see a redandunt space in Runner folder "ios/Runner /Info.plist"

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate in the Terminal to the file and execute plutil ./Info.plist which should show you where the issue is. Then fix in a text editor

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918946/info-plist-the-operation-couldn-t-be-completed-xcbutil-propertylistconversion/60239580#60239580)